# How runtime knows the exact type of a boxed value type?

Tags: c#, boxing, unboxing

I understand what boxing is. A value type is boxed to an object/reference type and is then stored on managed heap as an object. But I can't get thru unboxing.

Unboxing converts your object/reference type back to the value type

```
int i = 123;          // A value type
object box = i;       // Boxing
int j = (int)box;     // Unboxing
```

Alright. But if I try to unbox a value type into another value type, for example, long in above example, it throws InvalidCastException

```
long d = (long)box;
```

It leaves me with an idea that may be runtime implicitly knows the actual TYPE of value type boxed inside "box" object. If I am right, I wonder where this type information is stored.

**EDIT:**

Since `int` is implicitly convertible to `long`. This is what confusing me.

```
int i = 123;
long lng = i;
```

is perfectly fine because it has no boxing/unboxing involved.

Comment: What about box.GetType()?

Comment: The runtime knows the type of *every* object. Boxed values are no different.

Comment: Let's assume you have a `Ball` which is value type, you put a ball in  the `GlassBox`. Does that prevents you from knowing it is a ball inside a glass box? You can clearly see that isn't it? Just like that..

Comment: This is a slightly confusing question. Imagine you created a `Foo` instance (reference type), and then assigned that to an `object` variable. Would you not also expect the same exception if you tried to cast it to a `Bar` instance (also a reference type)? As @JonathonReinhart said, boxing/unboxing doesn't really come into it.

Comment: @DanielKelley, I admit I didn't mention about my confusion, that when boxing/unboxing comes into play, even conversion from an implicitly convertible type doesn't work. See my edit.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When a value is boxed it gets an object header.  The kind that any type that derives from System.Object has.  The value follows that header.  The header contains two fields, one is the "syncblk", it has various uses that are beyond the scope of the question.  The second field describes the type of object.

That's the one you are asking about.  It has various names in literature, most commonly "type handle" or "method table pointer".  The latter is the most accurate description, it is a pointer to the info the CLR keeps track of whenever it loads a type.  Lots of framework features depend on it.  Object.GetType() of course.  Any cast in your code as well as the *is* and *as* operators use it.  These casts are safe so you can't turn a Dog into a Cat, the type handle provides this guarantee.  The method table pointer for your boxed *int* points to the method table for System.Int32

Boxing was *very* common in .NET 1.x, before generics became available.  All of the common collection types stored *object* instead of T.  So putting an element in the collection required (implicit) boxing, getting it out again required explicit unboxing with a cast.

To make this efficient, it was pretty important that the jitter didn't need to consider the possibility that a *conversion* would be required.  Because that requires a lot more work.  So the C# language included the rule that unboxing to another type is illegal.  All that's needed now is a check on the type handle to ensure it is expected type.  The jitter directly compares the method table pointer to the one for System.Int32 in your case.  And the value embedded in the object can be copied directly without any conversion concerns.  Pretty fast, as fast as it can possibly be, this can all be done with inline machine code without any CLR call.

This rule is specific to C#, VB.NET doesn't have it.  Typical trade-off between those two languages, C#'s focus is on speed, VB.NET on convenience.  Converting to another type when unboxing isn't otherwise a problem, all simple value types implement IConvertible.  You write it explicit in your code, using the Convert helper class:

```
        int i = 123;                    // A value type
        object box = i;                 // Boxing
        long j = Convert.ToInt64(box);  // Conversion + unboxing
```

Which is pretty similar to the code that the VB.NET compiler auto-generates.

Comment: Thanks for the precise explanation. Answers from Luaan, Paval and Ritesh also explain the same thing overall in different ways but your's hit the sweet spot.

Answer (score 4):

It's because boxing instruction adds value type token into result object [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.box(v=vs.110).aspx). When you are unboxing value from object, this variable is known type (and size in memory). Therefore you must cast object to original value type.

In your example you even don't need to cast it from int to long, because it's an implicit cast.

Answer (score 2):

It is because when you do boxing instead of moving the value type from stack to heap, it creates a copy of it in heap and stores the reference of it in stack in a new stack box.
So your original stack object i.e. value type object along with its data type information remains in the stack and maintains its history.
Now at the time of unboxing, it compares the type of object from heap to original data type in stack and if it finds mismatch gives the error.
So, it is necessary to use same data type that you boxed while doing unboxing.

Answer (score 1):

Every reference object has a bunch of metadata associated with it. This includes the exact type of the given object (which is why you can have type safety at all).

So while the `int` is by-value, this information is actually missing (not that it matters), but once you box it, it creates a new object with all the necessary metadata. This also means that while an `int` is just 4 bytes, a boxed `int` is much more than that - you've got a reference now (4-8 bytes), the value itself (4) and the metadata (which includes the specific type handle). This is very different from e.g. C++, which allows you to cast any pointer to a pointer of any type (and leaving you to deal with the errors when you cast it wrong).

Again, all the by-reference objects have this metadata. This is quite an important part of the cost of reference types, but it is also the means by which you can be sure of the type safety. This also nicely shows how expensive `ArrayList` of `int` can really be, and why `int[]` or `List<int>` is much more efficient - even ignoring the costs of allocating (and more importantly collecting) heap objects and the boxing and unboxing itself, the 4 byte int could suddenly be 20 bytes, just because you're storing a reference to it :)